# python multiprocessing - process results as they are returned

Tags: multiprocessing, python-3.7

I am using python multiprocessing library to hash a bunch of files asynchronously (among other things) like so:

```
mt_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MP_SIZE)
pool_handler = mt_pool.starmap_async(hash_job, [(root, entry.path) for entry in scantree(root)])
```

the hash_job function returns a dictionary (file, result, status)
I would like to begin processing the results as they come in. something similer to:

```
good_results = []
if status == 0:
        good_results.append(job_result['result'])
else:
        logging.error("file {0} returned error: {1}").format(job_result['file'],job_result['file'])
```

I am assuming I would need to place the above code inside a while block of some sort.

can anyone help?

Comment: can you please list the order of the returned objects by  `hash_job` ?

Comment: having the definition of the  `hash_job` especially the type of the returned objects will be helpful (e.g file is `dataframe`, result is `list`,  and status is `boolean`)

Comment: it returns a dictionary of (str)file, (str)result, int(status). there is no particular order to the returned objects. what I do is loop through a directory recursively and for each file run a job.